# Я создаю игру с бесконечной трассой. Трасса генерируется не так, как хотелось бы

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, графика, sdl2, sdl

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На картинке изображена трасса. Управлением змейкой пока не занималась.
Нужно, чтобы повороты соединялись и трасса не изменялась внезапно (на картинке это показать невозможно). Также желательно убрать мерцание (если это возможно)

Весь код игры на данный момент (проблема в функции game):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//Screen dimension constants
constexpr int SCREEN_WIDTH { 700 };
constexpr int SCREEN_HEIGHT{ 635 };

SDL_Window* window{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* screenSurface{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* mainScreen{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* gameScreen{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* snake{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road0{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road1{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road2{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road3{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road4{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road5{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road0_left_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road1_left_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road2_left_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road3_left_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road4_left_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road5_left_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road0_right_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road1_right_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road2_right_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road3_right_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road4_right_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road5_right_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road0_left{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road1_left{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road2_left{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road3_left{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road4_left{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road5_left{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road0_right{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road1_right{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road2_right{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road3_right{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road4_right{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* road5_right{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg0{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg1{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg2{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg3{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg4{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg5{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg0_left_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg1_left_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg2_left_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg3_left_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg4_left_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg5_left_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg0_right_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg1_right_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg2_right_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg3_right_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg4_right_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg5_right_center{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg0_left{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg1_left{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg2_left{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg3_left{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg4_left{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg5_left{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg0_right{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg1_right{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg2_right{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg3_right{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg4_right{ nullptr };
SDL_Surface* bg5_right{ nullptr };

bool init();
bool loadMedia();
void close();

using namespace std;

int game()
{
    //Apply the image
    SDL_BlitSurface(gameScreen, nullptr, screenSurface, nullptr);

    //Update the surface
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

    int y0 = 635;
    int y1 = 495;
    int y2 = 355;
    int y3 = 215;
    int y4 = 75;
    int y5 = -65;
    int x0 = 280;
    int x1 = 280;
    int x2 = 280;
    int x3 = 280;
    int x4 = 280;

    bool is1 = false;

    bool has_turn = false;

    int a0 = 0;
    int a1 = 0;
    int a2 = 0;
    int a3 = 0;
    int a4 = 0;
    int a5 = 0;

    int a = 3;

    SDL_Rect dstrect_road0;
    SDL_Rect dstrect_road1;
    SDL_Rect dstrect_road2;
    SDL_Rect dstrect_road3;
    SDL_Rect dstrect_road4;
    SDL_Rect dstrect_road5;

    while (true) 
    {

        //Apply the image
        dstrect_road0.x = x2;
        dstrect_road0.y = y0;
        if (y0 > y1) {
            if(a == 1) {
                dstrect_road0.x = dstrect_road0.x + 140;
            }
            if(a == 2) {
                dstrect_road0.x = dstrect_road0.x - 140;
            }
            if (a == 0) {
                if (dstrect_road1.x != x2) {
                    dstrect_road0.x = dstrect_road1.x;
                }
            }
        }
        SDL_BlitSurface(road0, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road0);

        if (y0 == -65) {
            a = rand() % 3;
        }

        if (has_turn == true)
        {
            if (x2 == 280)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 140;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road5_left_center;
                    dstrect_road5_left_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road5_left_center.y = y0;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road5_left_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road5_left_center);
                }
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 420;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road0_right_center;
                    dstrect_road0_right_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road0_right_center.y = y0;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road0_right_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road0_right_center);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 420)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 280;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road0;
                    dstrect_road0.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road0.y = y0;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road0, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road0);
                }
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 560;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road0_right;
                    dstrect_road0_right.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road0_right.y = y0;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road0_right, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road0_right);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 140)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 0;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road0_left;
                    dstrect_road0_left.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road0_left.y = y0;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road0_left, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road0_left);
                }

                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 280;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road0;
                    dstrect_road0.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road0.y = y0;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road0, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road0);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 560)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 420;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road0_right_center;
                    dstrect_road0_right_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road0_right_center.y = y0;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road0_right_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road0_right_center);
                }
            }

            if (x2 == 0)
            {
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 140;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road0_left_center;
                    dstrect_road0_left_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road0_left_center.y = y0;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road0_left_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road0_left_center);
                }
            }
        }

        //Apply the image
        dstrect_road1.x = x2;
        dstrect_road1.y = y1;
        if (y1 > y2) {
            if (a == 1) {
                dstrect_road1.x = dstrect_road1.x + 140;
            }
            if (a == 2) {
                dstrect_road1.x = dstrect_road1.x - 140;
            }
            if (a == 0) {
                if (dstrect_road2.x != x2) {
                    dstrect_road1.x = dstrect_road2.x;
                }
            }
        }
        SDL_BlitSurface(road1, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road1);

        if (y1 == -65) {
            a = rand() % 3;
        }

        if (has_turn == true)
        {
            if (x2 == 280)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 140;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road1_left_center;
                    dstrect_road1_left_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road1_left_center.y = y1;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road1_left_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road1_left_center);
                }
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 420;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road1_right_center;
                    dstrect_road1_right_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road1_right_center.y = y1;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road1_right_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road1_right_center);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 420)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 280;
                    dstrect_road1.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road1.y = y1;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road1, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road1);
                }
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 560;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road1_right;
                    dstrect_road1_right.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road1_right.y = y1;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road1_right, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road1_right);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 140)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 0;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road1_left;
                    dstrect_road1_left.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road1_left.y = y1;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road1_left, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road1_left);
                }

                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 280;
                    dstrect_road1.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road1.y = y1;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road1, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road1);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 560)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 420;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road1_right_center;
                    dstrect_road1_right_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road1_right_center.y = y1;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road1_right_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road1_right_center);
                }
            }

            if (x2 == 0)
            {
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 140;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road1_left_center;
                    dstrect_road1_left_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road1_left_center.y = y1;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road1_left_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road1_left_center);
                }
            }
        }

        //Apply the image
        dstrect_road2.x = x2;
        dstrect_road2.y = y2;
        if (y2 > y2) {
            if (a == 1) {
                dstrect_road2.x = dstrect_road2.x + 140;
            }
            if (a == 2) {
                dstrect_road2.x = dstrect_road2.x - 140;
            }
            if (a == 0) {
                if (dstrect_road3.x != x2) {
                    dstrect_road2.x = dstrect_road3.x;
                }
            }
        }
        SDL_BlitSurface(road2, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road2);

        if (y2 == -65) {
            a = rand() % 3;
        }

        if (has_turn == true)
        {
            if (x2 == 280)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 140;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road2_left_center;
                    dstrect_road2_left_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road2_left_center.y = y2;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road2_left_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road2_left_center);
                }
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 420;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road2_right_center;
                    dstrect_road2_right_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road2_right_center.y = y2;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road2_right_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road2_right_center);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 420)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 280;
                    dstrect_road2.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road2.y = y2;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road2, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road2);
                }
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 560;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road2_right;
                    dstrect_road2_right.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road2_right.y = y2;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road2_right, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road2_right);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 140)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 0;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road2_left;
                    dstrect_road2_left.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road2_left.y = y2;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road2_left, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road2_left);
                }

                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 280;
                    dstrect_road2.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road2.y = y2;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road2, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road2);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 560)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 420;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road2_right_center;
                    dstrect_road2_right_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road2_right_center.y = y2;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road2_right_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road2_right_center);
                }
            }

            if (x2 == 0)
            {
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 140;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road2_left_center;
                    dstrect_road2_left_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road2_left_center.y = y2;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road2_left_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road2_left_center);
                }
            }
        }

        //Apply the image
        dstrect_road3.x = x2;
        dstrect_road3.y = y3;
        if (y3 > y4) {
            if (a == 1) {
                dstrect_road3.x = dstrect_road3.x + 140;
            }
            if (a == 2) {
                dstrect_road3.x = dstrect_road3.x - 140;
            }
            if (a == 0) {
                if (dstrect_road4.x != x2) {
                    dstrect_road3.x = dstrect_road4.x;
                }
            }
        }
        SDL_BlitSurface(road3, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road3);

        if (y3 == -65) {
            a = rand() % 3;
        }

        if (has_turn == true)
        {
            if (x2 == 280)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 140;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road3_left_center;
                    dstrect_road3_left_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road3_left_center.y = y3;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road3_left_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road3_left_center);
                }
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 420;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road3_right_center;
                    dstrect_road3_right_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road3_right_center.y = y3;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road3_right_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road3_right_center);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 420)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 280;
                    dstrect_road3.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road3.y = y3;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road3, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road3);
                }
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 560;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road3_right;
                    dstrect_road3_right.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road3_right.y = y3;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road3_right, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road3_right);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 140)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 0;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road3_left;
                    dstrect_road3_left.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road3_left.y = y3;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road3_left, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road3_left);
                }

                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 280;
                    dstrect_road3.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road3.y = y3;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road3, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road3);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 560)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 420;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road3_right_center;
                    dstrect_road3_right_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road3_right_center.y = y3;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road3_right_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road3_right_center);
                }
            }

            if (x2 == 0)
            {
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 140;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road3_left_center;
                    dstrect_road3_left_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road3_left_center.y = y3;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road3_left_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road3_left_center);
                }
            }
        }

        //Apply the image
        dstrect_road4.x = x2;
        dstrect_road4.y = y4;
        if (y4 > y5) {
            if (a == 1) {
                dstrect_road4.x = dstrect_road4.x + 140;
            }
            if (a == 2) {
                dstrect_road4.x = dstrect_road4.x - 140;
            }
            if (a == 0) {
                if (dstrect_road5.x != x2) {
                    dstrect_road4.x = dstrect_road5.x;
                }
            }
        }
        SDL_BlitSurface(road4, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road4);

        if (y4 == -65) {
            a = rand() % 3;
        }

        if (has_turn == true)
        {
            if (x2 == 280)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 140;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road4_left_center;
                    dstrect_road4_left_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road4_left_center.y = y4;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road4_left_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road4_left_center);
                }
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 420;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road4_right_center;
                    dstrect_road4_right_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road4_right_center.y = y4;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road4_right_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road4_right_center);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 420)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 280;
                    dstrect_road4.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road4.y = y4;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road4, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road4);
                }
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 560;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road4_right;
                    dstrect_road4_right.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road4_right.y = y4;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road4_right, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road4_right);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 140)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 0;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road4_left;
                    dstrect_road4_left.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road4_left.y = y4;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road4_left, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road4_left);
                }

                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 280;
                    dstrect_road4.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road4.y = y4;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road4, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road4);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 560)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 420;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road4_right_center;
                    dstrect_road4_right_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road4_right_center.y = y4;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road4_right_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road4_right_center);
                }
            }

            if (x2 == 0)
            {
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 140;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road4_left_center;
                    dstrect_road4_left_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road4_left_center.y = y4;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road4_left_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road4_left_center);
                }
            }
        }

        //Apply the image
        dstrect_road5.x = x2;
        dstrect_road5.y = y5;
        if (y5 > y0) {
            if (a == 1) {
                dstrect_road5.x = dstrect_road5.x + 140;
            }
            if (a == 2) {
                dstrect_road5.x = dstrect_road5.x - 140;
            }
            if (a == 0) {
                if (dstrect_road0.x != x2) {
                    dstrect_road5.x = dstrect_road0.x;
                }
            }
        }
        SDL_BlitSurface(road5, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road5);

        if (y5 == -65) {
            a = rand() % 3;
        }

        if (has_turn == true)
        {
            if (x2 == 280)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 140;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road5_left_center;
                    dstrect_road5_left_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road5_left_center.y = y5;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road5_left_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road5_left_center);
                }
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 420;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road5_right_center;
                    dstrect_road5_right_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road5_right_center.y = y5;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road5_right_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road5_right_center);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 420)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 280;
                    dstrect_road5.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road5.y = y5;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road5, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road5);
                }
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 560;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road5_right;
                    dstrect_road5_right.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road5_right.y = y5;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road5_right, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road5_right);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 140)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 0;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road5_left;
                    dstrect_road5_left.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road5_left.y = y5;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road5_left, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road5_left);
                }

                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 280;
                    dstrect_road5.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road5.y = y5;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road5, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road5);
                }
            }
            if (x2 == 560)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    x2 = 420;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road5_right_center;
                    dstrect_road5_right_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road5_right_center.y = y5;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road5_right_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road5_right_center);
                }
            }

            if (x2 == 0)
            {
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    x2 = 140;
                    SDL_Rect dstrect_road5_left_center;
                    dstrect_road5_left_center.x = x2;
                    dstrect_road5_left_center.y = y5;
                    SDL_BlitSurface(road5_left_center, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_road5_left_center);
                }
            }
        }

        //Apply the image
        /*SDL_Rect dstrect_snake;
        dstrect_snake.x = 285;
        dstrect_snake.y = 424;
        SDL_BlitSurface(snake, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_snake);*/

        //Update the surface
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

        SDL_Delay(20);

        //Apply the image
        /*SDL_Rect dstrect_bg0;
        dstrect_bg0.x = 280;
        dstrect_bg0.y = y0;
        SDL_BlitSurface(bg0, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_bg0);

        //Apply the image
        SDL_Rect dstrect_bg1;
        dstrect_bg1.x = 280;
        dstrect_bg1.y = y1;
        SDL_BlitSurface(bg1, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_bg1);

        //Apply the image
        SDL_Rect dstrect_bg2;
        dstrect_bg2.x = 280;
        dstrect_bg2.y = y2;
        SDL_BlitSurface(bg2, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_bg2);

        //Apply the image
        SDL_Rect dstrect_bg3;
        dstrect_bg3.x = 280;
        dstrect_bg3.y = y3;
        SDL_BlitSurface(bg3, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_bg3);

        //Apply the image
        SDL_Rect dstrect_bg4;
        dstrect_bg4.x = 280;
        dstrect_bg4.y = y4;
        SDL_BlitSurface(bg4, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_bg4);*/

        //Apply the image
        SDL_BlitSurface(gameScreen, nullptr, screenSurface, nullptr);

        //Apply the image
        SDL_Rect dstrect_snake1;
        dstrect_snake1.x = 285;
        dstrect_snake1.y = 424;
        SDL_BlitSurface(snake, nullptr, screenSurface, &dstrect_snake1);

        //Update the surface
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

        y0++;
        if (y0 >= 635)
        {
            y0 = -65;
            has_turn = true;
        }
        y1++;
        if (y1 >= 635)
            y1 = -65;
        y2++;
        if (y2 >= 635)
            y2 = -65;
        y3++;
        if (y3 >= 635)
            y3 = -65;
        y4++;
        if (y4 >= 635)
            y4 = -65;
        y5++;
        if (y5 >= 635)
            y5 = -65;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Start up SDL and create window
    if(!init())
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize!/n";
    }
    else 
    {
        if (!loadMedia()) 
        {
            cout << "Failed to load media!/n";
        }
        else 
        {
            //Apply the image
            SDL_BlitSurface(mainScreen, nullptr, screenSurface, nullptr);

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

            //main loop flag
            bool quit = false;

            //Event handler
            SDL_Event e;

            //While application is running
            while (!quit)
            {
                //Handle events on queue
                while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
                {
                    //User requests quit
                    switch (e.type)
                    {
                        case SDL_QUIT:
                            quit = true;
                            break;

                        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                            if (e.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
                                if ((e.button.x > 189 and e.button.x < 520) and (e.button.y > 468 and e.button.y < 620)) {
                                    game();
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Apply the image
            SDL_BlitSurface(mainScreen, nullptr, screenSurface, nullptr);

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

            //Free resources and close SDL
            close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

bool init()
{
    //Initialization flag
    bool success = true;
    //Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    {
        cout << "SDL initialization failed. SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError();
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Snake Runner",
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            SCREEN_WIDTH,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT,
            SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (window == nullptr)
        {
            cout << "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s/n" << SDL_GetError();
            success = false;
        }
        else {
            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
        }
    }
    return success;
}

bool loadMedia() 
{
    //Loading success flag
    bool success = true;

    //Load splash image
    mainScreen = SDL_LoadBMP("MainScreenSnake.bmp");
    gameScreen = SDL_LoadBMP("GameScreenSnake.bmp");
    snake = SDL_LoadBMP("snake.bmp");
    road0 = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road1 = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road2 = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road3 = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road4 = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road5 = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road0_left_center = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road1_left_center = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road2_left_center = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road3_left_center = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road4_left_center = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road5_left_center = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road0_right_center = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road1_right_center = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road2_right_center = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road3_right_center = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road4_right_center = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road5_right_center = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road0_left = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road1_left = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road2_left = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road3_left = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road4_left = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road5_left = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road0_right = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road1_right = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road2_right = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road3_right = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road4_right = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    road5_right = SDL_LoadBMP("road.bmp");
    bg0 = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg1 = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg2 = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg3 = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg4 = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg5 = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg0_left_center = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg1_left_center = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg2_left_center = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg3_left_center = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg4_left_center = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg5_left_center = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg0_right_center = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg1_right_center = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg2_right_center = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg3_right_center = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg4_right_center = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg5_right_center = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg0_left = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg1_left = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg2_left = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg3_left = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg4_left = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg5_left = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg0_right = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg1_right = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg2_right = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg3_right = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg4_right = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");
    bg5_right = SDL_LoadBMP("bg.bmp");

    if (mainScreen == nullptr) 
    {
        cout << "Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s/n" << "MainScreenSnake.bmp" << SDL_GetError();
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}

void close()
{
    //Deallocate surface
    SDL_FreeSurface(mainScreen);
    mainScreen = nullptr;
    gameScreen = nullptr;
    road0 = nullptr;
    road1 = nullptr;
    road2 = nullptr;
    road3 = nullptr;
    road4 = nullptr;
    road5 = nullptr;
    road0_left_center = nullptr;
    road1_left_center = nullptr;
    road2_left_center = nullptr;
    road3_left_center = nullptr;
    road4_left_center = nullptr;
    road5_left_center = nullptr;
    road0_right_center = nullptr;
    road1_right_center = nullptr;
    road2_right_center = nullptr;
    road3_right_center = nullptr;
    road4_right_center = nullptr;
    road5_right_center = nullptr;
    road0_left = nullptr;
    road1_left = nullptr;
    road2_left = nullptr;
    road3_left = nullptr;
    road4_left = nullptr;
    road5_left = nullptr;
    road0_right = nullptr;
    road1_right = nullptr;
    road2_right = nullptr;
    road3_right = nullptr;
    road4_right = nullptr;
    road5_right = nullptr;
    bg0 = nullptr;
    bg1 = nullptr;
    bg2 = nullptr;
    bg3 = nullptr;
    bg4 = nullptr;
    bg5 = nullptr;
    bg0_left_center = nullptr;
    bg1_left_center = nullptr;
    bg2_left_center = nullptr;
    bg3_left_center = nullptr;
    bg4_left_center = nullptr;
    bg5_left_center = nullptr;
    bg0_right_center = nullptr;
    bg1_right_center = nullptr;
    bg2_right_center = nullptr;
    bg3_right_center = nullptr;
    bg4_right_center = nullptr;
    bg5_right_center = nullptr;
    bg0_left = nullptr;
    bg1_left = nullptr;
    bg2_left = nullptr;
    bg3_left = nullptr;
    bg4_left = nullptr;
    bg5_left = nullptr;
    bg0_right = nullptr;
    bg1_right = nullptr;
    bg2_right = nullptr;
    bg3_right = nullptr;
    bg4_right = nullptr;
    bg5_right = nullptr;

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = nullptr;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: 1087 строк, начинаем code review!

Comment: Это тот случай, когда программисту следует напомнить что копипаста зло. Столько однотипного кода, который можно сократить... Отлаживать такое - не самое простое дело.